# Firebase RTDB Flutter app: Multiple Databases

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

So, I am using the Blaze plan in Firebase and I have multiple realtime databases. I was wondering how I can connect to a specific one through my Flutter app.

`FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();` connects me to the default database, but how can I connect to another one?

Answer (score 2):

Using `FirebaseDatabase.instance` is just a shorthand notation to getting the default `FirebaseApp` instance, which is typically auto-initialized from the values in your `google-services.json`/`google-services.info.plist`

You can explicitly initialize a `FirebaseApp` with configuration data in your code. A snippet of the relevant code from an app I happen to be working on:

```
  final FirebaseApp  app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: "defaultAppName",
    options: Platform.isIOS
        ? const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '....',
            gcmSenderID: '...',
            databaseURL: '...',
          )
        : const FirebaseOptions(
            googleAppID: '...',
            apiKey: '...',
            databaseURL: '...',
          ),
  );*/
  FirebaseDatabase(app: app).setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  FirebaseDatabase(app: app).reference().child("/rounds/r1").orderByValue().onChildAdded.forEach((event) => {
    print(event.snapshot.value)
  });
```

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the suggestion. Using your code snippet, my app kept crashing every time it tried creating a `FirebaseApp` instance. Tried putting it in a `try/catch` but nothing would print out; just `Lost connection to device.` Any tips to resolve this?

Comment: Nothing, the app simply crashes without throwing anything. I tried using debugger tools but it looks like the app crashes before its able to print anything out.